# Composer: two vendor directories (one of them is symlinked) - shared library autoloading

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, autoloader

I need two vendor directories to be autoloaded within a Symfony 2 application. I will first explain why I need this, to make everything more clear:

I have many small projects/websites written in Symfony 2 that all `symlinks` a `shared library` which provides domain models etc.

One of the projects app structure:

```
|- app
|- library -> ../library (symlink)
|- src
|- vendor
|- web
```

The `library` project has many and important vendors (doctrine etc.), so I cannot install the vendors of `library` inside every's project `vendors` directory. This would take alot of disk space.

Do I need to `merge` the two vendors (`[root]/vendors` and `[root]/library/vendors`) so that they are all autoloaded but not copied? If I do this, my composer.lock would fail I guess, because the vendors live in different directories.

How would this be done with Composer? Any tips, I am out of ideas.

Thanks!

Comment: "Takes up too much disk space" shouldn't be an argument these days, unless you can tell us how much disk space all these dependencies really use that you save.

Comment: @Sven Well, diskspace is one thing, maybe not that big of an issue. But the big deal is that you need to update your vendors on xxx different places when you "copy" everything. If you symlink it, you have it all in one place. Which in my case is the best solution.

I already required both autoloaders, this works fine. But you will still have differences because the composer.lock file is not aware of the symlink.

Comment: The key feature of Composer is to exactly allow to have different versions of a dependency inside every application you maintain. That way you have the freedom to update one application at a time and deal with the possible integration woes. Having one version centrally managed is one of the reasons nobody likes PEAR. It forces you to update everything at the same time. And also, by using a centrally managed library that is not mentioned as an application dependency, you don't know which parts are being used and cannot put the application elsewhere (read: another server) easily.

Comment: @Sven I think you are right, I trying to get best of both worlds. But indeed, seperatly managed dependencies seems to be better. Also, the vendors take 380MB (for the shared library alone). It is quite a lot.  Well, thanks for getting me on the right path :)

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony 2 app/autoload.php file can be used to add additional directories to load from.

```
/**
 * @var $loader ClassLoader
 */
// The Composer generated autoloader
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// An additional directory to load from
$loader->add('Cerad',   __DIR__  . '/../../cerad2/src');

// Majic
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));

return $loader;
```

Comment: But how would I manage to keep both vendors, so the one in [root]/vendors and [root]/library/vendors in sync, so they do not contain copied vendors. In order words, both autoloaders (from library and the main) needs to know both dependencies. I already know how I can get them autoloaded, but it's more versions that can collide etc. when symlinking vendors.

Comment: I guess I answered the wrong question.  Don't use symlink and don't sweat the disk space issue unless it actually becomes a problem.